# Without Sharing class failed on validation rule

Tags: validation-rule, dml, without-sharing

Custom apex trigger initiates a change on opportunity(from within a without sharing static class).
Which than apply DML update operation.
Validation rule fails on opportunity.
The validation rule check weather the change was from a certain profile.id(system administrator)

Without sharing class runs within a system execution context, 
Is it suppose to fail?
Is it possible to run it as a specific user?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Without sharing class runs within a system execution context, Is it suppose to fail?

Even though the code runs in system mode, the running user's profile doesn't change. So yes, the validation rule should apply.

> Is it possible to run it as a specific user?

No, otherwise it would cause a data integrity issue. Only possible option is to run without or without sharing as you know.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, 
the user and profile is the same with or without sharing. Without sharing only by-passes permissions, but it does NOT run-as Admin, hence... the validation rule fails